# NetCDF-Java: how to write unsigned attribute?

Tags: netcdf

I'm trying to write an unsigned value to a `valid_range` attribute in an nc4 file using NetCDF-Java 4.3, but it is always written as signed. This makes viewing applications display the data incorrectly. Sample code:

```
Array array = Array.factory(DataType.byte, new int[] { 2 });
array.setUnsigned(true);
array.setObject(0, 0);
array.setObject(1, 255);
Attribute attr = new Attribute("valid_range", array);
log.debug("{}", attr);
```

This prints out:

```
valid_range = 0UB, -1UB
```

But the CDL for that attribute in the resulting file is:

```
colour1:valid_range = 0b, -1b ;
```

When I look at that variable in ToolsUI 4.3, it's all blank because everything is outside of the false range. I tried using shorts to represent unsigned bytes; that works for `valid_range` but fails for the `_FillValue` attribute:

```
WARN  Nc4Iosp - _FillValue type must agree with var = colour2 type short!=byte
```

How should unsigned types be written to attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the variable is unsigned the valid_range values should be widened and stored as unsigned integers.

```
Array array = Array.factory(DataType.byte, new int[] { 2 });
```

Change that to...

```
Array array = Array.factory(DataType.INT, new int[] { 2 });
```

This came from Unidata's website.

https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/docs/BestPractices.html

Comment: Good find. That page also says that the `_FillValue` attribute must have the same data type as the variable it is applied to (not widened) - so there's no rule that fits both `_FillValue` and `valid_range`.

Answer (score 3):

1. Netcdf-Java stable version is 4.6, and  4.3 is pretty out of date, esp for writing to netcdf4. So you should see how/if 4.6 works.
2. Netcdf-Java version 5 has added unsigned data types to make this easier, though thats not yet stable.
3. Widening valid_range is a good solution. You must leave _FillValue as the same type as the variable, though as you noted.
4. Why do you want to set valid_range? IMO, its not a good practice, because it forces client software to check for validity. Dont use it unless you really need it. Documenting the actual_range is more useful.

Comment: This was just for storing NODATA values. I think we wanted to support both `_FillValue` and `valid_range` because by default our output files inherit the attributes of the inputs, and some must have used that attribute. I guess we could convert it to `_FillValue` easily enough tho.